# How to make the text in UILabel fill all space in UILabel?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = @"Hello";
[label sizeToFit];
CGSize size = label.frame.size;
```

Usually we get the size of the label in this way, but text in the UILabel does not fill all space in it, there's always some margin around the text. That makes drawing label difficult to be exactly the same as visual draft. Anyone could help ？

for example: If you want to put an icon at the bottom of some text, let the margin between them be, for example 50px, and you write icon.frame = CGRectMake(10,textLabel.frame.size.height + textLabel.frame.origin.y + 50, 100, 100); but since the text can't fill all space in UILabel, so the margin in this way should be a bit larger than it should be. So I want to figure out a better way, thanks.

Comment: chk thsi http://iosdeveloperfamily.webs.com/apps/blog/show/24245473-automatic-spacing-between-labels

Comment: thx, but that doesn't solve my problem. What I mean is that if you want to put an icon at the bottom of some text, let the margin between them be, for example 50px, and you write icon.frame = CGRectMake(10,textLabel.frame.size.height + textLabel.frame.origin.y + 50, 100, 100);  but since the text can't fill all space in UILabel, so  the margin in this way should be a bit larger than it should be.

Comment: then you can calculate height of ur string and set your label height and  icon y value accordibngly chk this http://iosdeveloperfamily.webs.com/apps/blog/show/24374934-calculate-height-of-label-when-string-are-of-different-lengths-

Answer (score 2):

try with this bellow method which returns dynamic height of `UILable` with its text content... we this method you can set frame of `UILable` with its text content...

```
-(float) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(NSString*) text: (UIFont*)withFont: (float)width :(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode
{
[text retain];
[withFont retain];
CGSize suggestedSize = [text sizeWithFont:withFont constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(width, FLT_MAX) lineBreakMode:lineBreakMode];

[text release];
[withFont release];

return suggestedSize.height;
}
```

and use it like bellow...

```
     UILabel *lblAddress = [[UILabel alloc]init];
    [lblAddress setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 31, 200, 50)];        
    lblAddress.text = @"your Text ";
    lblAddress.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    lblAddress.numberOfLines = 0;
    lblAddress.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12];

    lblAddress.frame = CGRectMake(lblAddress.frame.origin.x, lblAddress.frame.origin.y, 
                             200,[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:lblAddress.text :lblAddress.font :200 :UILineBreakModeWordWrap] ); 

    lblAddress.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [self.view addSubview:lblAddress];
```

See [My Blog](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/11/set-uilabel-with-adjust-content-text.html)..

i hope you get some idea from this post...